# Which scripture has the following verse about Sri Vishwamitra?

Tags: identification-request, vishwamitra

Can someone tell me from where this verse is taken?

The verse comes in the title song of a TV serial on Maharshi Sri Vishwamitra.

It starts at 0.25

https://youtu.be/wfxrSyrajyQ?t=24s

> Srushtikartaa Lokakartaa Sarvakaarana Kartru Hare
>
> Vishwamitro Brahmavettaa Srushte Srushte Pravikhyaataha
>
> Maha Veero Maha Tejo Vishwamitro Mahamunihi

Comment: [This website](http://patwari.org/mantralaya/m621.html) has some details...

Comment: Can you include the point of time in the video that particular verse occurs? Or maybe include the Devanagari text.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra It's already included. It starts at 24 seconds.

Comment: Yes, it starts at 24 seconds, but it does not show the above lines. At which point does it actually show these lines?

Comment: @GabeHiemstra not showing but hearing...